# CSS width inherit issues

Tags: html, css

I need to have my div have the same width as the parent div, however my width: inherit does not do the job. When I do inspect element, there is

```
<span class="..." id="..."> == $0
```

in between the divs. Please let me know if you need more info

CSS:

```
.Select--multi {  

    .Select-value {
    background-color: #ebf5ff;
    /* Fallback color for IE 8 */
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #c2e0ff;
    /* Fallback color for IE 8 */
    border: 0px solid rgba(0, 126, 255, 0.24);
    color: #000000;
    display: list-item;
    font: 16px Roboto;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style-type: none;       
    list-style-position: inside; 
    width: inherit;
    }
```

Comment: Are you use a CSS pre-processor? If not, then your CSS has invalid syntax. Also note that `span` elements are inline. If you want it to fill all of the available horizontal space of its parent, use `display: block` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: use 'width: 100%' for child element.

Comment: can you provide [runnable script](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your sample is both incorrect and incomplete (e.g. how is the CSS used in the HTML?), and at the same time it contains (for this question) a lot of unneeded garbage. Please clean it up and provide a sample that is as short as it can be.

Comment: As others have said, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your question talks about a div but there is no div in your example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and Karthik thank you that is what I was looking for. I gave the portion of the code I knew had to be fixed, I did not think the rest was relevant as I briefly described what was going on.  In terms of the "unneeded garbage", I simply did not know if there were conflicts between properties or whatnot so I included them.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use width: inherit in the child element. Just use width: 100%. Then the child element will stretch to the parent width if have the display: list-item property set.

Answer (score 0):

First, the provided code snippet is not CSS. you are either using scss or less.

Second,The `inherit` keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element. That means your parent element should have defined the corresponding property to get it effect it in the child element.

The answer is to set `width:100%;` in the child element style.